# McAfee enterprise 8.5 & SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

While trying to upload a file into the sharepoint 2007 document library, We are facing some issues.

McAfee enterprise 8.5 is installed on the client machine (XP), will it be the issue?

Comment: Can you temporarily disable McAfee to test your theory?  What exactly are the "issues"?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell more about the kind of issues are you facing? Do you get any error message?

Common problems include:
 - The file exceeds the maximum size.
 - The file type is blocked (many types are blocked by default).

Both settings are managed on the farm level, therefore you will need admin access to the server in order to modify them.